# Retrofit wrap response in a generic class internally

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I have a sealed class like below,

```
sealed class ApiResult<T>(
    val data: T? = null,
    val errors: List<Error>? = null
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T?) : ApiResult<T>(data)
    class Failure<T>(
        errors: List<Error>,
        data: T? = null
    ) : ApiResult<T>(data, errors)
}
```

And this is my Retrofit API interface,

```
interface Api {
    @POST("login")
    suspend fun login(@Body loginRequestDto: LoginRequestDto): ApiResult<LoginResponseDto>
}
```

What I want to achieve is, internally wrap the LoginResponseDto in BaseResponseDto which has the success, error, and data fields. Then put them in the ApiResult class.

```
data class BaseResponseDto<T>(
    val success: Boolean,
    val errors: List<Int>,
    val data: T?
)
```

In this case, LoginResponseDto is my data class. So, Retrofit should internally wrap the LoginResponseDto in BaseResponseDto then I will create the ApiResult response in my custom call adapter. How can I tell Retrofit to internally wrap this? I don't want to include the BaseResponseDto in the API interface every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending the whole day, I could achieve it. I had to create a custom converter. Here it is,

```
class ApiConverter private constructor(
    private val gson: Gson
) : Converter.Factory() {
    override fun responseBodyConverter(
        type: Type,
        annotations: Array<out Annotation>,
        retrofit: Retrofit
    ): Converter<ResponseBody, *> {
        val baseResponseType = TypeToken.get(BaseResponseDto::class.java).type

        val finalType = TypeToken.getParameterized(baseResponseType, type)

        return Converter<ResponseBody, Any> { value ->
            val baseResponse: BaseResponseDto<*> =
                gson.fromJson(value.charStream(), finalType.type)
            baseResponse
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun create(gson: Gson) = ApiConverter(gson)
    }
}
```

Now I don't have to specify the BaseResponseDto every time in the API interface for retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

If you want to implement your own solution you would need a custom Retrofit CallAdapter.

My recommendation would be [Sandwich](https://github.com/skydoves/sandwich) an Open source Library which does the exact same thing.

If you want to implement your own soultion here's one way

[Modeling Retrofit Responses With Sealed Classes and Coroutines](https://getstream.io/blog/modeling-retrofit-responses/)

Comment: Unfortunately, Sandwich doesn't fulfill my needs. I was able to implement a custom call adapter to wrap the response in my ApiResult class. But what I want to achieve is, Retrofit will provide a BaseResponseDto<LoginResponseDto> response when I pass just LoginResponseDto type in the API interface.

Comment: I have solved it with the combination of custom converter and call adapter. I have posted an answer as well.